# Thermodynamic dependence of chemical reaction equilibrium point

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

Consider a chemical reaction like

$$
(-\nu_1) R_1 + (-\nu_2) R_2 \Leftrightarrow \nu_3 R_3 + \nu_4 R_4
$$

with the Gibbs free energy

$$
dG = -SdT + VdP + \sum_i \mu_i dN_i \, .
$$

The amounts of each reagent are given by
$$
N_i(\xi) = N_i^{(0)} + \nu_i \xi
$$

yielding an overall Gibbs free Energy like,
$$
dG = -SdT + VdP + \left(\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i\right) d\xi \, .
$$

$ \xi $ is the extent to which the reaction has taken place which I expect to have a temperature and pressure dependence (eg. [water dG vs. T](https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/fuel-cells/figures/gibbs_free_energy.png))

How do you solve for this dependence?

Comment: Suppose that the temperature and pressure are controlled so that they are held constant as the reaction mixture is approaching equilibrium.  That tells you that, at equilibrium, the G of the mixture is minimized.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't tell me what the $\xi$ of equilibrium is. I'd like to know how fast the reaction would progress. I guess I'm assuming there's some point when the reaction is no longer favorable.

Comment: You have $\sum{\nu_i \mu_i}=0 $, and $\mu_i$ is a function of $\xi$

Comment: @ChesterMiller, how do you get the dependance? Do you have to look it up in a table or use Stat Mech to get the partition function? The tables for Gibbs free energy of formation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Gibbs_free_energy_of_formation  (which I assume are the $\mu$'s) don't include a dependance on any of the $ T, P, \mu $ like I would expect physics would depend on.

Comment: Would you be willing to settle for the chemical potential equation for an ideal gas species in terms of its partial pressure?

Comment: Short answer: No, but I'd be entertained by the solution. Are you referring to the Activity coefficient and the Van t' Hoff equation? I actually asked this because I was concerned about the use of the Ideal gas equation to derive both. They say that it applies to solutions, but I have only seen derivations using the ideal gas law. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32385/derivation-of-van-t-hoff-equation-for-temperature-dependence-of-equilibrium-con https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5811/unit-of-the-equilibrium-constant-contradiction-of-bridgmans-theorem/5814#5814

Comment: The ideal gas law is the starting point for advancing to more complicated mixtures in which non-idealities associated with molecular interactions need to be accounted for.

Comment: If so, could you explain in your answer why the Ideal gas is an appropriate starting point for chemicals in solution? That's why various sources seemed to imply, but I am not convinced (or possible very confused).

Comment: Have you mastered the development for the case of an ideal gas first?  From your questions in the original post, it doesn't seem that you have.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean "the case for the ideal gas", but I have done a graduate level course in stat mech and read through derivation for van t' Hoff equation and I have no problem understanding those. I may dislike the assumptions they make initially, but only because I was in search of something more general. In my question, I was trying to preserve temperature and pressure dependance for equilibrium, hence not holding them constant like you recommended.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow.

Comment: Naively (not a chemist), I would imagine that temperature would have some effect on equilibrium position $\xi$ of a chemical reaction. So claiming that I am holding temperature constant seemed wrong as I might want to change temperature during the reaction. Also, I don't see how we can use gas equations for fluids.

Comment: What you are doing is determining the equilibrium constant at a specified temperature, whatever that temperature might be.  You are not following the progress of the reaction within the reactor.  The equilibrium constant only applies when the system has reached equilibrium.  This is a calculation that is being done "off line," and then applied to the final equilibrium state of the reactor (irrespective of path).

Comment: You can't vary the equilibrium point $\xi$ by varying the temperature or pressure?

Comment: Who says?  If you change the temperature, then you change the equilibrium constant (van't Hopf equation).  Varying the pressure will vary $xi$ if the number of moles changes.  So certainly varying the temperature or the pressure varies $xi$.

Comment: That relation is what I am trying to find, but without assuming an ideal gas. The Van t' Hoff equations (akaik) assumes an ideal gas.

Comment: No way.  It applies to a real gas too, if you use the fugacity in the equilibrium relation.

Comment: And solutions? I can't name a good example, but things like weak acid/base reactions or organic reactions.

Comment: Before you start doing liquid solutions, you need to have a better understanding of how to solve equilibrium problems with ideal- and real gases.  The development for liquid solutions is just an extension of how gases are handled.

Comment: You probably need to swap the constitutive equation for the fluid then? If the ideal gas law isn't good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was over thinking it. It doesn't seem that difficult, but let me illustrate with an example.

Given we are interested in 4 species of particles, we would expect a total Hamiltonian like,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}\big(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{P}; \vec{N}\big) &= \sum_{i=1}^4 \mathcal{H}_i\big(\mathbb{Q}_i \subset \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{P}_i \subset \mathbb{P} ; \vec{N}_i\big) + U\big(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{P}\big)
\end{align}
where $ | \mathbb{Q}_i | = | \mathbb{P}_i | = N_i $.

Thinking about a single species system, computing the [Isothermal-Isobaric ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal%E2%80%93isobaric_ensemble) gets you the Gibbs free energy,
\begin{aligned}
     G(T, P, N) &= -k T\log \Delta (N,P,T) \\
         &= -k T \log \left[ {\frac  {C}{h^{3}}}\int {\mathrm  {e}}^{{-\beta (H(q,p) + PV)}}~d^{{3N}}q~d^{{3N}}p~dV \right]
\end{aligned}

If you compute this for a multi-species particle, then you can get $ \sum_i \mu_i \nu_i = \sum_i \frac{dG}{dN_i}\frac{dN_i}{d\xi} = 0 $ as the chemical equilibrium point as a function of $ P, T $.

**Ideal Gas Example**

For an ideal gas (see Section 2.4 [these lecture notes](http://micro.stanford.edu/~caiwei/me334/Chap9_NPT_Grand_Canonical_Ensemble_v04.pdf)),
\begin{align}
G(T, P, N) = -N k_B T \log \left[ \frac{k_B T}{P} \cdot \frac{(2\pi m k_B T)^{3N/2}}{h^{3N}} \right]
\end{align}
[in chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62803/how-to-derive-the-gibbs-free-energy-for-an-ideal-gas), its written like $ G(T, P, N) = G(P_0) + nRT \ln\left(\frac{P}{P_0}\right) $. *I'm ignoring the fact that this differs from the Stat Mech version and just using the stat mech version*.

Going back to the multi-species problem, if we drop the interaction term $ U\big(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{P}\big) $ and assume an ideal gas, then
\begin{align}
G(T, P, N) &= -\sum_i N_i k_B T \log \left[ \frac{k_B T}{P} \cdot \frac{(2\pi m_i k_B T)^{3N_i/2}}{h^{3N_i}} \right] \\
  &= \sum_i G_i
\end{align}
*I am just taking $ P, T $ to be the same for each species because they are Lagrange multipliers and Laplace transform variables, so having multiple doesn't make much sense to me*

Then,
\begin{align}
\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i = \sum_i \frac{dG_i}{dN_i}\frac{dN_i}{d\xi}
  = - \sum_i \nu_i k_B T \log \left[ \frac{k_B T}{P} \right] + 2 \big( N^{(0)}_i + \nu_i \xi \big) k_B T \log \left[\frac{(2\pi m_i k_B T)^{3/2}}{h^{3}} \right]
\end{align}

Setting this equal to zero, taking $ m_i = m $, and the [translation partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translational_partition_function) $ {\displaystyle \Lambda ={\frac {h}{\sqrt {2\pi mk_{B}T}}}} $,
\begin{align}
\xi = \frac{\sum_i \log \left[ \left(\frac{k_B T}{P}\right)^{\nu_i} \Lambda^{6 N^{(0)}_i} \right]}{\sum_i \log \left[\Lambda^{-6 \nu_i } \right]}
\end{align}

Comment: "I am just taking P,T to be the same for each species because they are Lagrange multipliers and Laplace transform variables, so having multiple doesn't make much sense to me" Love that sentence. Just shows the difference between thinking like a experimentalist and a theoretician.